# Specflow reusing When as Then

Tags: selenium, specflow

I am currently automating my tests with Specflow and Selenium. I have created simple functions which I would like to re-use with Specflow. The problem I am encountering is, once I have defined a step as When, later on I cannot re-use this step with Then.

So for example:

```
Scenario: 1
Given user navigates to 'http://www.anyURL.com/'
When user inserts 'data' into field with ID 'id'
And user clicks on button with ID 'id'
Then user sees 'x' amount of search results
```

So this is scenario 1. Now in scenario 2 I want to use 
"When user inserts 'data' into field with ID 'id'" 
as: 
"Then user inserts 'data' into field with ID 'id'"

But as in my code, my function starts with [When(@"user inserts '(.*)'.... Sepcflow doesn't match this.

I remember that Cucumber used to do this automatically.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In specflow you just have to add another attribute to the method you want to bind:

```
[When(@"user inserts '(.*)'"]
[Given(@"user inserts '(.*)'"]
public void UserInertsData(string data)
{
     ....
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! Its that easy? I just failed to find this solution in the Specflow documentation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can also create slightly differently worded steps by simply using more attributes of the same type on a method

Comment: [Given, When(@"user inserts '(.*)'"] --> is even shorter

Comment: @ward will that work though? is that not saying `[Given()]` with no regex and `[When(@"user inserts '(.*)')]` which could end up with different matching cases